# How to change Realm singleton attribute value

Tags: swift, singleton, realm

I have a [`Realm`](https://realm.io) object:

```
class TransactionDB: Object {

    dynamic var transactionID : Int = -1
    dynamic var registrationPlate : String = ""
    dynamic var locationID : Int = 0
    dynamic var time : String = ""
    dynamic var subscription : String = ""
    dynamic var startTime : NSDate = NSDate() 
    dynamic var endTime : NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var status : Int = -2
    dynamic var requestType : Int = -1
    var extensions : List<ExtensionDB> = List<ExtensionDB>()
    dynamic var price : Double = 0
    dynamic var currency : String = ""
    private dynamic var test : Int = 10

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "transactionID"
    }

    class var sharedInstance : TransactionDB {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = TransactionDB()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    static func saveOrUpdate {
        // ......
    }
```

and a singleton version for it. So I have one object over many controllers when screens change.
A few days back I was using some older Objective-C version of Realm but now I changed to the Swift-only version 1.0.2 and I'm trying to fix all the problems.

So now it came to part that when I try to call stuff like:

```
TransactionDB.sharedInstance.time = ""
```

I get an exception. However, after I do the following, it works:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    TransactionDB.sharedInstance.time = ""
}
```

So am I creating the singleton wrong or is this just the way it has to be done? Because, for me, it is a little annoying that I would always have to use a `try` block when I want to change the value of some attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the first line of the [Realm docs for the write section](https://realm.io/docs/swift/1.0.2/#writes).

It states:

> All changes to an object (addition, modification and deletion) must be done within a write transaction.

So yea, it's just how you have to do it.

Comment: I just thought that it could work without it because I don't want it to be written to DB until it's finished. I already figured it out that I'll probably have to create temp class to have an object like that.

Comment: Until what's finished? The logic that prepares the values to be updated? Just keep all your logic outside of/before the transaction block, and only perform the transaction block using variables of everything prepared, once you're ready. Don't mix your app logic in with the transaction block. Do as little as you can inside the transaction block.

Comment: That is what I was doing, I had a shared instance of object that was never written into DB so that I could change things and when everything was set I created new object with those values and saved it. But somehow once I'we set the shared attributes I could't change them without transaction block.